# How to create Image with AWS SDK for Ruby - Version 2

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

In AWS SDK Version 1, we can create image from an instance with the following method:

```
ec2.images.create(:instance_id => "i-123", :name => "my-image")
```

How we can handle it by Version 2? Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer, here is the example:

```
ec2_instance.create_image({
  dry_run: false,
  name: "String", # required
  description: "String",
  no_reboot: false,
  block_device_mappings: [
    {
      virtual_name: "String",
      device_name: "String",
      ebs: {
        snapshot_id: "String",
        volume_size: 1,
        delete_on_termination: false,
        volume_type: "standard", # accepts standard, io1, gp2, sc1, st1
        iops: 1,
        encrypted: false,
      },
      no_device: "String",
    },
  ],
})
```